# Problem when migrating from Authlogic to Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, devise

I referred this [Migrating from Authlogic to Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840072/migrating-from-authlogic-to-devise)
and followed it to get the database structure required by devise ready. 
However I get this error on my sign_in page

```
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

This is my Request:

```
{"commit"=>"Sign in","authenticity_token"=>"oWXrE+EdhO4ScuaBzPBqCnpYsal1QcDC483ygVSs0fw=","user"=>{"password"=>"password", "email"=>"email@email.com"}}
```

I'm using Rails 2.3.8 and hence using Devise v 1.0.

This is my sessions/new view :

```
<% form_for resource_name, resource, :url => session_path(resource_name) do |f| -%>
  <p><%= f.label :email %></p>
  <p><%= f.text_field :email %></p>
  <p><%= f.label :password %></p>
  <p><%= f.password_field :password %></p>

  <p><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></p>
<% end -%>
```

Any ideas to get this to work? Thanks !

**EDIT**

Here's the stack trace:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)):
devise (1.0.8) lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb:139:in `find_for_authentication'
devise (1.0.8) lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb:117:in `authenticate'
devise (1.0.8) lib/devise/strategies/database_authenticatable.rb:16:in `authenticate!'
warden (1.0.3) lib/warden/strategies/base.rb:53:in `_run!'
warden (1.0.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:303:in `_run_strategies_for'
warden (1.0.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:298:in `each'
warden (1.0.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:298:in `_run_strategies_for'
warden (1.0.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:271:in `_perform_authentication'
warden (1.0.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:90:in `authenticate'
devise (1.0.8) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:36:in `authenticate'
devise (1.0.8) app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:19:in `create'
warden (1.0.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
warden (1.0.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.0.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
```

Anything to do with warden dependency?

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be in your sessions/new view, everything looks fine to me there. Does the error give any more details in the "Application Trace" about where the error occurred?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, using warden 0.10.7 and devise 1.0.8
I tried the `User.find` in the console and was OK.

To fix it, I removed the class method `authenticate` on my User-Model:

```
#def self.authenticate(login, pass)
#  find(:first, :conditions => ["login = ? AND password = ?", login, sha1(pass)])
#end
```

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be occuring in a `User.find` call, which is strange. Do you have anything that might be overriding the default find method?

Try this in the console and see if you get an error.

```
User.find(:first, :conditions=>{:email=>'email@email.com'})
```