# Is it possible to use Devise gem / engine for hosted multisite setup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, authlogic

I currently use authlogic for my Rails-hosted multi-site application by using the `authenticates_many :user_sessions` method on my `Site` model.

I want to change over to Devise. Does anyone know if this is possible and if so, how?

Thanks a lot,
Richard

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840072/migrating-from-authlogic-to-devise

Comment: This one involves SSO and the other one doesn't. I don't think it's a dupe.

Answer (score 3):

There was a great post on [Devise and Omniauth with SSO](http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2010/12/16/multiple-applications-with-devise-omniauth-and-single-sign-on/) by [Josh Software](http://joshsoftware.com/).